# Make instances point away from centre of the curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a curve that I'm instancing some xmas light on each vertex. How can I rotate the points so my instances point outwards from the centre of the curve?

[image: instances]

And here is my geometry nodes setup

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: instances]

[image: node tree]

So I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I'm not sure if you have the same vertex normals when you convert a curve to mesh, so I decided to use the tangent from the circle points, and just add PI/4 to point them outwards.

You could of course just use the normal from the curve to points and add PI/2 if that's your preference.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it simply like this:

[image]

Comment: hey thanks, that's what i'm trying to do in my node tree above, I want to use the curve i'm starting with, so that I can easily move it around afterwards using its control points. Any idea why it doesn't work in my example?

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: I found a way to do this, thanks for your help